# Regex keep \w, hyphen between words and remove digits

Tags: python, regex

I struggle to extend following expression to match and remove digits:

```
[^\w -]|_|-(?!\w)|(?<!\w)-
```

Example:

```
123 !"§$%&/()= äüöüÄÖÜÄßßßß hello-123, hello-hello, hello-.
```

Exprected Output:

```
äüöüÄÖÜÄßßßß hello hello-hello hello
```

Comment: Maybe `-?\d+-?|[^\w -]|_|-(?!\w)|(?<!\w)-` will do? See https://regex101.com/r/TKXNcn/1

Comment: I added several other options for you to consider in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
-?\d+-?|[^\w -]|_|-(?!\w)|(?<!\w)-
-*\d+(?:\.d+)?-*|[^\w -]|_|-(?!\w)|(?<!\w)-
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TKXNcn/1).

The `-?\d+-?|` part matches

- `-?` - an optional `-`
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `-?` - an optional `-`
- `|` - or (the rest of the alternatives).

The `-*\d+(?:\.d+)?-*` part matches float values, too, and matches zero or more hyphens on both ends of the number.

Replace `-` with `\W` to match any non-word char.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/i9ZFWo):

```py
import re
text = '123 !"§$%&/()= äüöüÄÖÜÄßßßß hello-123, hello-hello, hello-.'
print( re.sub(r'-?\d+-?|[^\w -]|_|-(?!\w)|(?<!\w)-', '', text).strip() )
# => äüöüÄÖÜÄßßßß hello hello-hello hello
```